# Rails Admin stylesheet not found when open from website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have a rails app, with a rails admin backend, uploaded on AWS. 
There is a very odd issue that I face. 
When I open the app by typing in the ip address. xx.xxx.xxx.xx:9292/admin. The rails admin opens fine.

But when I open this from the loadbalancer domain that I have added, https://mydomainname.com/admin. I get a broken stylesheet. When I clicked inspect, it showed me the that assets folder contiaining the stylesheets were not found.

Comment: Are you using relative or absolute paths? Might it be an error with CORS?

Comment: Could you include the errors from your browser console?

Comment: Can you please attach your browser console error?

Comment: Request URL: https://mydomainname.com/assets/rails_admin/rails_admin-6e6cdda87a83b1874fa02d2e154d6cb7ca3894be4ad833e5b7710439e41667d2.css
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: 
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade


I dont know if this is relevant, but anyway
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-8DpLL+goFWb6CP1arKUYfPscDHQ+G+Jkyu+XqwIrT8Y='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.